# Cannot translate from Dafny to Python using recommended "dafny build --target:py A.dfy"

Tags: dafny, code-translation

I am trying to use the Dafny-to-Python compiler that is suggested in Dafny's reference (25.7.7): http://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef.html#2577-python

However, I cannot run the first step for it in the terminal: `dafny build --target:py A.dfy`, since I get the error: `Dafny: Error: unknown switch: --target`. I use `Use /help for available options` as they suggest, but have no idea on how to solve.

Just in case, I also attempted using the old version of the command (see 25.8.11. in the same reference): `dafny Hello.dfy -compileTarget:py` but then got message `Dafny: Error: Invalid argument "py" to option compileTarget`.

Any idea? Note that the authors themselves clearly state that *The Dafny-to-Python compiler is still under development.*

PS: I usually use Dafny in Visual Studio and not in the terminal, so maybe I lack some kind of library or something.

Comment: Maybe a version problem? With v3.10.0 from https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/tag/v3.10.0 the syntax with `build --target:py A.dfy` works for me, as well as the alternative `./dafny translate --target py A.dfy`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I just did `dafny /version` and saw my version is `Dafny 3.3.0.31104`, how can I update it? Do you now if this also affects the version in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not fully sure how it works on Windows (I use Linux myself) but I think you can just download the Windows binaries from https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/download/v3.10.0/dafny-3.10.0-x64-win.zip, extract the files in some folder and run Dafny from there (which is what I did for Linux and that worked). To integrate with Visual Studio you should probably modify the properties of your Dafny project in Visual Studio to change the compiler path to your new installation.

Comment: Indeed, I am using Mac, so I guess it gets closer to the approach in Linux, isn't it? I thought I could use some kind of `'Dafny /update'` or something.. Can I do as follows? I will keep using Visual Studio with the previous versions (in order not to break anything), whereas I will download these `3.10` binaries in a new folder "NewDafny". I will then move those files (done with Visual Studio) that have extension `.dfy` and that I want to translate to Python to "NewDafny" and see whether the command works in there. Does this make sense?

Comment: I guess it makes sense - however there is no risk in breaking Visual Studio, if you change the project properties and things don't work anymore then you just change the properties back to their previous values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!! I will try this and come back if. A last question: I am trying to find binaries like the ones you offered in the link, but I cannot find them for Mac, do you have an idea? I already tried https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/download/v3.10.0/dafny-3.10.0-x64-mac.zip and https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/download/v3.10.0/dafny-3.10.0-mac.zip and https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/download/v3.10.0/ etc

Comment: At the bottom of the page I linked earlier (https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/tag/v3.10.0) there are two Mac versions listed, arm64-osx and x64-osx, you should pick the one that matches your CPU.

Comment: Thanks again! I am now trying to test it, but getting a message that "Apple cannot check it for malicious software". Will come back once I test it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the new CLI nor the Python compiler are supported by the very outdated version of Dafny you are using. You are presumably not using the [correct](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dafny-lang.ide-vscode) VS Code extension, so I would start there. As of today, this should install 3.10.0 at `/Users/$USER/.vscode/extensions/dafny-lang.ide-vscode-3.0.3/out/resources/3.10.0/github/dafny/Dafny.dll`. To see how to use the dll, try hitting `F5` with a Dafny file opened in VS Code. The Python compiler is complete and passes all tests these days.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to install this version inside VS Code but I can't, I uninstall and install using the link you sent but my Dafny stays on version 2.5.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, I see the path you sent and see: `../.vscode/extensions/dafny-lang.ide-vscode-2.5.0/..`

Comment: Do you have the latest VS Code installed?

Comment: I think not, but I am currently having some problems with VS Code, so maybe that is another issue.. In any case, I just achieved installing lates Dafny '3.10.0.41215' and, as you noted, it worked: it created 3 files out of one .dfy, and the most interesting one seems to be "module..." I will have several questions about that now in another post hehe Thanks a lot!